# How to show php passed results to ajax without refreshing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to do is when a user type an email to the inputbox ajax will pass the value automatically to php.

My problem is the result only show if I try to refresh the page

html:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var countTimerEmailName = setInterval(
        function ()
        {
        emailName();            
        }, 500);

var data = {};
    data.email = $('#email').val();

function emailName(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"Oppa/view/emailName.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function (result) {

        $("#imageLink").val(result.user_image);
        $("#profileImage").attr('src', result.user_image);
        $("#emailNameResult").html(result.user_lname);
        $("#emailCodeResult").val(result.user_code);        

        }
    });
};           
});
```

Comment: Could you please post your php code so that we can help you find the problem

Comment: @Khalid php is fine the ajax just wont show the result if the page inst refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You're handling it wrong. jQuery has particular events to do these things.

Take this for example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('keyup', '#email', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        val = $(this).val();
        console.log("Value: " + val);
    });
});
```

It will look what is in the below input field as the user types. (<sup>*which is what I presume you're trying to do?*</sup>)

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TejG/)

You could simply remove that `console.log()` and replace it with your ajax request. (*The above example will run as the user types*.)

---

Alternatively you could use `change()` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change', '#email', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        val = $(this).val();
        console.log("Value: " + val);
    });
});
```

Which will run after the value of the text box has changed. (*When the user clicks out of the text box or moves somewhere else on the page.*)

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6TejG/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

Because you dont need declare function in `ready()` and you need yo get the email value after any change. Now you only get the value when the page is ready.

```
function emailName( email ){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"Oppa/view/emailName.php",
        data: 'email=,+email,
        cache: false,
        dataType:"JSON",
        success: function (result) {

        $("#imageLink").val(result.user_image);
        $("#profileImage").attr('src', result.user_image);
        $("#emailNameResult").html(result.user_lname);
        $("#emailCodeResult").val(result.user_code);        

        }

    });

};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email').change(function(e) {
        emailName( this.val());
    });
});
```